# How i convert different date python format?

Tags: python, date

I have `dd-MMM-yyyy` dates. How do i convert this to `yyyyMMdd`, in Python ?

For example i need to convert 20-Nov-2002 to 20021120

Answer (score 33):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` to read the date in a specific format and then use `.strftime()` to write it back in your required format. Example -

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('20-Nov-2002','%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20021120'
```

Formats -

> %d - 2 digit date
>
> %b - 3-letter month abbreviation
>
> %Y - 4 digit year
>
> %m - 2 digit month

More details about different supported formats can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` module to do that, like this:

```
import re                                                                   
text = '20-Nov-2002'.replace('Nov', '11')                                                        
print(re.sub(r'(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)', r'\3-\1-\2', text))
```

output:

```
2002-20-11
```

But if you want convert the all month, not just `Nov` to `11`.

you can use the `datetime` module like this:

```
import re, datetime           
month = datetime.datetime.strptime('Nov', '%b').strftime('%m')   

text = '20-{month}-2002'.format(month=month)
print(re.sub(r'(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)', r'\3-\1-\2', text))
```

And the output is the same.